# Pandas - merge all all columns with the same substring

Tags: python, pandas

I have many columns that contain the same substring and i want to merge them to one using OR function.

So i want to merge all columns that have the same

```
dfin.columns.str.split("_").str[1]

first_RG7509|   first_YY6124|   last_YY6124|    first_WE4818|first_AA7542|  last_RG7509

1|0|1|1|0|0
```

and the output should be:

```
RG7509|YY6124|WE4818|AA7542

1|1|1|0
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Merge or drop ?

Comment: It's not clear, from your example, what logic you want to implement. Please, clean your post and add clean and reproducible example,

Comment: i want to merge all columns that have the same `dfin.columns.str.split("_").str[1]`

Comment: Yes, but how is the merge done? Sum, mean, first?

Comment: @TobSta What you mean by merge? What dtype this columns have?

Comment: I think by "merge" the OP means "aggregate" - the OP wants to aggregate by a logical or.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take the transpose, groupby the second part of each string, then transpose back:

```
>>> df.T.groupby(df.T.index.str.split('_').str[1]).sum() > 0).T.astype(int)
    AA7542  RG7509  WE4818  YY6124
0   0   1   1   1
```

Comment: You can avoid this transpose trick using axis=1 (generally this is the case for many other pandas functions too)!

Comment: Thanks, @AndyHayden - I did not know that. UVing your answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can do a groupby with axis=1:

```
In [11]: df
Out[11]:
   first_RG7509  first_YY6124  last_YY6124  first_WE4818  first_AA7542  last_RG7509
0             1             0            1             1             0            0

In [12]: df.groupby(lambda x: x.split("_")[1], axis=1).sum()
Out[12]:
   AA7542  RG7509  WE4818  YY6124
0       0       1       1       1
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do a duplicated check aswell:

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.split('_').str[1]
df = (df.T.sort_values(by=0)
          .reset_index()
          .drop_duplicates(subset='index', keep='last')
          .set_index('index').T)
```

Full proof:

```
import pandas as pd

data = '''\
first_RG7509|first_YY6124|last_YY6124|first_WE4818|first_AA7542|last_RG7509
1|0|1|1|0|0'''

df = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(data), sep='|')

df.columns = df.columns.str.split('_').str[1]
df = (df.T.sort_values(by=0)
          .reset_index()
          .drop_duplicates(subset='index', keep='last')
          .set_index('index').T)
```